# Git - multiple developers on same branch

Tags: github, bitbucket, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I am pretty new to Git and I am using sourcetree as a client.

I know that in Git two developers work on the same branch at a time since they have local copies of the remote branch.

So here is a scenario :

A and B are working on a branch feature/release1.0

A commits code to local branch.
Now B commits the code and pushes it to the remote branch as well.
Now A will have to push his changes as well as Pull changes made by B.

So what will A do in this case ?

Comment: As good examples of workflows with git I would sugest: [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows)

Answer (score 5):

In this case, A should pull B's changes down first, make sure everything works, commit, and push.

Generally we (my team) don't work quite like that.

When we have two developers working closely on a feature, we work on separate branches and merge into a shared feature branch.

Among the advantages of this is that you can commit and push on your own schedule, which means that you can make your code work without worrying about the other developer's changes and **your code makes it to the server quicker.**  That is, it's somewhere other than your own machine, somewhere that's probably backed up.

Answer (score 2):

***A*** must git pull first (some merge may be needed) and than push the code.

If ***A*** try to push his code in the first place, git will tell that the remote and local branches have diverged and instruct the developer to pull the code first.

If you pay attention to git commit error messages (and git status messages) you will always know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, A has to get the changes from B (git pull) before pushing her changes. It is likely she has to deal with some conflicts, which should be resolved locally before pushing the code.

Apart from that, you should probably reconsider your branch scheme to avoid this kind of conflicts. Would it be possible to work in different branches? For instance, by redefining the tasks, to be more fine-grained.

Moreover, it is weird, at least for me, the name or the branch `feature/release-1.0`. Looks like there are releases by features basis, os something like that. Take a look at http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. See how the release branches are fed from the developing branch, and this one receives the commits from the features branches.

Hope it helps!